# Creatng a new child with a relation to an existing parent creates a new parent at dbContext.save()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, one-to-many, dbcontext

I have a one to many, parent child relationship created using code first entity framework models.

The result of the code below creating a new child which has a reference to an existing parent is that i end up with a new parent entry.

I have seen a suggested solution to this being attaching the parent to the context or changing it's EntityState. However i don't think this works as the two models exist in different contexts.

The different contexts has always seemed odd to me but I read somewhere that it is common to do this to keep each model modular so stuck to that. (even though they use the same connection string ect)

So questions are:
How do i ensure the Child is associated with the existing parent and not associated to a newly created one?

Even if the different dbContexts are not causing the issue, is this wise?

My Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Information_Id,Information_Title,Information_LinkText,Information_URLBody")] Information information, int InformationContainer_Id)
        {
            InformationContainerDBContext dbContainer = new InformationContainerDBContext();

            //information.Information_Container = (from p in dbContainer.InformationContainers where p.InformationContainer_Id == InformationContainer_Id select p).ToList()[0];
            information.Information_Container = dbContainer.InformationContainers.Single(o => o.InformationContainer_Id == InformationContainer_Id);


            if (ModelState.IsValid)

            {
                dbContainer.Entry(information.Information_Container).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

                db.Informations.Add(information);
                db.SaveChanges();


                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(information);
        }
```

My Models:

Parent:

```
public class InformationContainer
    {
        [Key]
        public int InformationContainer_Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string InformationContainer_Title { get; set; }

       [InverseProperty("Information_Container")]
        public List<Information> Informations{ get; set; }

    }

    public class InformationContainerDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public InformationContainerDBContext()
            : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataDBString"].ConnectionString)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<InformationContainer> InformationContainers { get; set; }
    }
```

Child:

```
public class Information
    {
    [Key]
    public int Information_Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Information_Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Information_LinkText { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Information_URLBody { get; set; }

    public InformationContainer Information_Container { get; set; }
}

public class InformationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public InformationDBContext()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataDBString"].ConnectionString)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Information> Informations { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
@model eCommSite.Areas.Admin.Models.Information

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Information Pages - Create";
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ selector: 'textarea' });</script>


<h2>Information Pages</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Create</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Information_Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Information_Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Information_Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Information_LinkText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Information_LinkText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Information_LinkText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Information_Container, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select name="InformationContainer_Id">
                    <option value="1">Help</option>
                    <option value="2">Company</option>
                    <option value="3">Information For Parents</option>

                </select>
              </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Information_URLBody, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10" style=" height:500px!important; width: 80%;">
                <textarea id=" wysiwyg"
                          style=" height:350px; width: 500px;"
                          name="Information_URLBody"></textarea>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: try with removing `dbContainer.Entry(information.Information_Container).State = EntityState.Unchanged;` `information.Information_Container` should be in **changed** state if you add new information entry to it.

Comment: I think these multiple contexts are causing more harm then good. In fact, I fail to see how it can help to have multiple contexts pointing to the same database. If someone has any clues, please enlighten me. I would really like to know.

Comment: @rraszewski this was an attempt at a solution, it can be ignored and the result is the same

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please ... there's a lot going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things were going on here:

First , having multiple DbContext was mad, and with some work I merged them all.

(If you're reading this post.... Having just one DbContext to maintain is huge and no matter how fearful you are of the possible work involved i highly recommend merging, especially if you're like me who only had multiple context due to inexperience.)

Secondly, I was adding references to entities from another context and also references to entities rather than their id's  this created new entities when save changes was called

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the extra DbContext, have only one. Add this property to your `Information` class, make it a foreign key:

```
public int InformationContainer_Id { get; set; }
```

Your context should look like this:

```
public class InformationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public InformationDBContext()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataDBString"].ConnectionString)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Information> Informations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InformationContainer> InformationContainers { get; set; }
}
```

Since `InformationContainer_Id` is a foreign key, your controller code should like this and it should work.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Information_Id,Information_Title,Information_LinkText,Information_URLBody")] Information information, int InformationContainer_Id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        information.InformationContainer_Id = InformationContainer_Id;
        db.Informations.Add(information);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(information);
}
```

Comment: Can i do this instead?
 [ForeignKey("InformationContainer_Id")]

  public InformationContainer Information_Container { get; set; }

Comment: Yes, you'll have to do that. Sorry, I assumed you'd take care of it.

Comment: So it looks like this was likely to lead to the solution but i decided to combine the DB context at the same time and now no matter what i do ( including completely deleting both tables , both controllers, both views and re building them ) i get a DB migrations error even though for all purposes the contexts are completely new. I now have to fix that and once sorted i will be able to check this solution

Comment: I wrote an answer for that scenario too, but then reverted it thinking it might not be useful in this case. Since you have decided to merge contexts, I will get that version back. For DB migration issues, if you are good with rebuilding the entire database, you can use these commands. `update-database -TargetMigration $InitialDatabase`. Delete all migration class files from Migrations folder and run `Add-Migration "NewModel"` followed by `update-database -verbose`.

Comment: I get the following error: Either the parameter objname is ambiguous or the claimed objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

Comment: I think the problem is a manually dropped the tables... but i would think migrations would just rebuild them?

Comment: Yes, migration should re-create all the tables for you. If you are getting too many issues,  and if you can afford to create a new db, start with a fresh one.

Comment: I can't really start a new DB as it has a lot of tables that are already set up and if i start playing around with those i will see similar errors and cause everything i've done to fail! I don't understand why after deleting everything it can think there are migrations to be done. To it, everything should be new models,new controllers, a new dbcontexts ect. I'm finding EF so unintuitive and constantly frustrating!

Comment: Out of interest when you create dbcontexts and you have many models using the same connection string do you just create one dbcontext with many dbsets and if so do you put it in it's own file for clarity?

Comment: Only one db context. For your problem try this, find a most recent migration "x" to which you'd like to rollback. Then run update-database -TargetMigratin "x". After that delete all migration cs files generated after X. Then run add-migration and then update-database.

Comment: One more thing, you can try pointing your conn string to a new db. That way your existing db will remain as-is. You can always revert.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i think i managed to rebuild the table to the point where i'm not getting migration areas before seeing this but the reminder about using a different connection string is a good thing to note. Hilariously somehow when the views were created they have dropped all CSS just looking into why that would happen.... a really odd bug? (perhaps i selected the wrong option during controller creation)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Information_Id,Information_Title,Information_LinkText,Information_URLBody")] Information information, int InformationContainer_Id)
        {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)        
                {
                    InformationContainerDBContext dbContainer = new InformationContainerDBContext();
                    var infContainer = dbContainer.InformationContainers.Single(o => o.InformationContainer_Id == InformationContainer_Id);

                    infContainer.Informations.Add(information);
                    dbContainer.SaveChanges();


                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(information);
        }
```

If you add navigation property to collection of already existed property, it will be added to database too.

Comment: `information.Information_Container` is retrieved using dbContainer context. Hence, it is already attached.

Comment: Again, a similar problem. When you add to `infContainer.Informations`, it is added to dbContainer context. We are not calling SaveChanges() on that context. So it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: You can add this as edition to answer (and to question too). It seems is typo in question (and copy-paste in answers)